# What does GROUP BY do to two unjoined tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am sharing a code from a book here.
Here, the group by is on two fields which are from different UNJOINED tables( A and B). It seems not intuitive to me that you can group by fields on unjoined tables. Can anyone explain how is it possible?

```
    select a.deptno from emp a, 
    (select max(avg_sal) max_avg_sal from (select  
    avg(sal) avg_sal from emp group by deptno) ) b 
    group by a.deptno, b.max_avg_sal 
    having avg(a.sal) = b.max_avg_sal
```

Result according to book

```
    **deptno**
    10
```

Comment: I do not see a union in this query. Are you referring to a join between sets "a" and "b"?

Comment: @Hilarion yes, a and b are not joined , yet their fields are used as GROUP BY

Comment: Updated the code for clarity

Answer (score 1):

This is just a horrible example of code.  I would not recommend any book that uses commas in the `from` clause.

This is simply a subquery in the `from` clause.  It has a `join` condition, in the `where` clause.

Instead of the comma, you could use `JOIN`.  And instead of the `WHERE`, you could use `ON`.

There are better ways to write such a query.  In preference to aggregating before the `JOIN`. I would go with:

- Window functions, either `row_number()`, `rank()` or `max()`.
- A correlated subquery in the `where` clause.
- Specific aggregation functions that can get the employee with the highest salary.

Last on the list would be pre-aggregation, which is what this query does.

Comment: Given the use of widely deplored ANSI SQL 89 syntax, it's ironic that the book is entitled *Oracle SQL Tricks and Workarounds: Expert Guide to Oracle SQL Excellence* :) To be fair, the book does cover explicit JOIN syntax two pages later.

Comment: This code tried to do a group by on two fields which are unjoined - is it usual?

Comment: @theluncheonmeat . . . Yes, it is weird.  The `JOIN` is in the `HAVING` clause.  Like I say, this is a pretty bad query.  It s a shame it is on the printed page.

Comment: updated code for clairty